# Having trouble running a mechanize script on Linux when it runs fine on windows

Tags: python, authentication, https, mechanize

Well here is the thing, I have written a Python script that connects to my works webpage and downloads my most recent paycheck. It works great in windows but when I move this script to my server that is running Debian it fails to redirect past the initial page. Is there a difference between the platforms? Searching for hours now has not resulted in any useful information for me. I have made sure that both systems and running the same version of mechanize but the Python versions are different (EDIT: now both are identical), although just a bit different.

```
Both systems are running identical versions of Python and mechanize.
# >> python -V
Python 2.7.1
#mechanize >> print(mechanize.__version__)
(0, 2, 4, None, None)
```

Now I have created a stripped down test script just for testing. This is so I can compare the results easily. In Windows the script will return the final page that contains a list of all the paychecks available while in Linux it will only print the initial page that should be redirecting to the login page. I feel that mechanize under Linux is either not redirecting at all or it is just not setting a cookie that is needed to proceed.

Any ideas? suggestions? I am basically asking if there is a difference in mechanize between Windows and Linux. Since the package contents are from the same source my guess is no but then what is causing this issue?

Here is the code that I am using to test. Obviously I have left out the correct username and password :)

```
import mechanize;
import urllib;

#constants
URL_OPEN = "https://ep.upsers.com/ep-s/UPSRegistration/UPSLogin";#set a cookie
URL_SECURE = "https://ep.upsers.com/gems-secure/epay_eng.html";
URL_PAYCHECK = "https://ep.upsers.com/gems-secure/psc/hrprod/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/M_UPS_MENU.VW_PYCHK_M.GBL?Page=PYCHKDAT_M&Action=U";#lists paychecks
VIEWALL = "#ICViewAll";


def testConnection(username, password):
    success = "no connection: ";

    try:
        #get a cookie to use later
        mechanize.HTTPSHandler();
        request1 = mechanize.Request(URL_OPEN);
        response1 = mechanize.urlopen(request1);

        #attempt our login
        postdata = {"user": username,"password": password};
        post = urllib.urlencode(postdata);
        headers =  {"User-agent" : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)"};
        request2 = mechanize.Request(URL_OPEN, post, headers);
        response2 = mechanize.urlopen(request2);

        #navigate to paycheck page
        request3 = mechanize.Request(URL_PAYCHECK);
        response3 = mechanize.urlopen(request3);

        success = response3.read();

    except Exception as ex:
        success += str(ex);

    print(success);
#end testConnection

testConnection('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
```

Initially I thought that the user-agent might need to changed but there is no change in the results.

NOTE: Now both versions of Python and mechanize are identical. 
NOTE: I have observed that while examining the headers at each request that the cookie is not being set/stored on Linux but in Windows it is fine.

Comment: Just an update. I have narrowed this down to the cookies not being set/saved from the initial request. I made sure to try running this as root and it has full permissions (chmod 777). Searching for 'mechanize saving cookies' is not helping. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that before you go after the deep suspects, try clearing the obvious differences: download Python 2.7 (no need to install it) and see if the behavior matches Windows.

Here's a 'build and run 2.7' copy-n-paste:

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.1/Python-2.7.1.tgz
tar -xzf Python-2.7.1.tgz
cd Python-2.7.1/
./configure && make
./python /path/to/your/script
```

Comment: How exactly would I run the script under Python 2.7 without installing it on the system? Google has yielded no results on this matter.

Comment: I think you can decompress a source archive, make, then run: "PYTHONPATh=*PATHTOPY* *PATHTOPY*/python script". I'm building and will report soon :)

Comment: Tried running under Python 2.7 with no joy.... I have found out that after examining the headers being sent at each request that the cookies are not being set/stored. Permissions for the script are set to full access and I am running it as root.

Comment: BTW. TY for the exact 'copy-n-paste' I was leaning towards this as a temporary solution to help debug. Looks like it comes down to a difference between Debian and Windows.

Comment: NP. I know it doesn't make much sense, but have you tried setting a cookiejar? http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/hints.html

Comment: AS a last resort, the Mechanize mailing list could help: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/wwwsearch-general

Comment: tried the cookie jar using just urllib2 and cookielib outside of mechanize and still it is not saving. This is leading me to believe that this is not a mechanize problem specifically but a permissions issue or something other than what I am finding.

Comment: Maybe something above the Python layer, like SSL or having a proxy upstrem of your Debian server? Can you login from that machine at all (from a browser or something like curl)?

Comment: I've run out of ideas. I have noticed that there seems to be a weird loop happening only on the Linux system. The site seems to redirect ok then is redirected back to the original page. At least thats what the cookies url are telling me.

Answer (score 0):

Which user executes the script on the server and what privileges does it have?

You're several changes to the execution environment at the same time:

1. Python version.
2. Operating system.
3. User
4. User environment (users with home directories are different).

Try to narrow it to one change at a time. Testing over a virtualized Linux on your Windows machine would be a good idea.

Comment: I did not set up a virtual environment under windows but I did manage to duplicate the environments as closely as possible between the two OSes. I am now running matching versions of both Python and mechanize between the two. The only difference now is the OS, Windows vs Debian.